# Module's new release not showing link to download

Tags: community-official-site

I created a new branch for a module I co-maintain, today. I followed the instructions and the branch is showing up. But, the problem is that the download links and dates are absent.

[image: snap]

How do I create them? What extra work needs to be done?

Comment: Not sure if you have to do anything else off the top of my head, but I do know that it's not instant.  From the time you make a new release, etc., it takes a few hours to appear.

Comment: @PatrickKenny You're right, it took some time for the compressed versions to appear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal.org automatically create download file for the module's revision, so you need to wait for the same.